# Rails 4 live search with keyup in javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, search

I have a Rails 4.2.1 app with Ruby 2.2.2.  I've implemented basic search with Ransack and am using Ajax for a remote call to prevent page loads on search.

What I'm trying to do is use the jQuery `keyup` functionality so when a user starts typing in the search box it will yield the results in realtime.  Below is my code.  The jQuery/JS I wrote in application.js works fine in a Rails 3.2.x app (where I pulled it from previously), but it does not work at all in Rails 4.2.1.

**application.js**

```
 $("#inventory_search input").keyup(function() {
   $.get($("#inventory_search").attr("action"), $("#inventory_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$("#search").html("<%= escape_javascript render("search") %>");
$("#results").html("<%= escape_javascript render("results") %>");
```

**_search.html.erb**

```
  <div class="pull-right" style="margin-right: 25px">
    <%= search_form_for(@q, url: "/inventory", method: :get, :id => "inventory_search", :remote => true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.search_field :asset_number_or_asset_name_or_asset_serial_cont, placeholder: 'Search...', class: 'form-control' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

**_results.html.erb**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Asset Number</th>
      <th>Asset Name</th>
      <th>Serial Number</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Manufacturer</th>
      <th>Asset Type</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
   <% @assets.each do |a| %>      
      <tr>
        <td><%= a.asset_number %></td>
        <td><%= a.asset_name %></td>
        <td><%= a.asset_serial %></td>
        <td><%= a.asset_model %></td>
        <td><%= a.asset_manuf %></td>
        <td><%= a.asset_type.try(:name) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'View', inventory_path(a), :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-info' %> <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_inventory_path(a), :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-warning' %></td>

      </tr>
  </tbody>
  <% end %>
<%= will_paginate @assets %>
```

**Edit Log excerpt when typing in input**

```
Started GET "/inventory?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Basset_number_or_asset_name_or_asset_serial_cont%5D=di&_=1434896540287" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-21 09:22:22 -0500
Processing by InventoryController#index as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"asset_number_or_asset_name_or_asset_serial_cont"=>"di"}, "_"=>"1434896540287"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered inventory/_search.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Asset Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "assets".* FROM "assets" WHERE (("assets"."asset_number" ILIKE '%di%' OR "assets"."asset_name" ILIKE '%di%') OR "assets"."asset_serial" ILIKE '%di%')  ORDER BY asset_number ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
  Rendered inventory/_results.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered inventory/index.js.erb (22.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 59ms (Views: 52.5ms | ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)
```

As you can see the Ajax is firing and catching my input in this case I was typing "di"  but no results show, and also if I clear the field it does not return all o the default scoped results.

Any help or guidance with this would be greatly appreciated.  If my question is not clear or you need further information, please ask!

Comment: So, what happens? Is the request being made? What's in the logs? JS console? "It doesn't work" isn't super-helpful.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I'll output a sample Rails log entry in my question.  When I start typing the ajax fires, but no results show up.  Also in the JS Console I see no errors at all, so I'm pretty sure my syntax is right.  What's interesting is that this same bit of code I wrote works excellent in Rails 3.2.x but now in 4.2.1 it doesn't work.  Could this be a turbolinks issue?

Comment: @DaveNewton 2 years later and running into the same problem with rails 5.1.3.  it fires a JS request but stops after I type the first character.  I'm using turbolinks load too on the function, but with no joy.